# blocking specific dns servers

Tags: domain-name-system, firewall, cisco, routing

We want to block specific DNS server requests on our network.

We tried null routing the DNS servers that were to be blocked, and it seems DNS requests are still getting through.

Any suggestions welcome.

Comment: ...are you sure you're not caching some of the old DNS values on the clients?

Comment: Yep, cache cleaned on our test boxes.

Comment: What do you mean block specific DNS servers? Do you mean that you want to block DNS queries to specific DNS servers that users may configure their DNS clients to use?

Comment: @joeqwerty - We want to block DNS server requests (port 53). Yes.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Best bet is to block the DNS server IP at your firewall. That would stop any and all requests for sure.